# Can i add publish setting file from VSTS to deploy project on Microsoft azure

Tags: azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

i am trying to deploy the project from VSTS to azure i have publish setting file  i need to know how to use publish setting file in pipeline to deploy the project on azure. or any other solution to deploy on azure.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. I am afraid this question is likely to be badly received by the community because it shows no evidence of your having done any research at all. Please edit the question to show what you have tried so far and what the results were, any error messages, etc. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can store the plain password in the secret variable of build/release, then specify the password through MSBuild argument (`/p:Password={variable}`).

After that you can specify the public profile (`.pubxml` file instead of `.publishsettings` file) in **Visual Studio Build** task (e.g. `/p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile="{profile name}"`)

Alternately you can write a script and add a `Batch Script` task to run the script to deploy on Azure. Please refer to [Deploying to Azure from VSTS using publish profiles and msdeploy](https://shazwazza.com/post/deploying-to-azure-from-vsts-using-publish-profiles/) for details.

You can also use the [`Azure App Service Deploy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/targets/webapp?view=vsts&tabs=yaml#azure-app-service-deploy-task) task to deploy the Azure Web App. Please refer to [How to deploy to Azure using Team Services Release Management](http://mohamedradwan.com/2018/02/12/how-to-deploy-to-azure-using-team-services-release-management/) for details.